# Understanding SQL self-join

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I am trying to understand SQL Self-joins. I have the following table 'persons' which has firstname, lastname, address and city of the employee (source W3Schools):

```
mysql> select * from persons;
+------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| P_id | LastName  | FirstName | Address      | City      |
+------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|    1 | Hansen    | Ola       | Timoteivn 10 | Sandnes   | 
|    2 | Svendson  | Tove      | Borgvn 23    | Sandnes   |
|    3 | Pettersen | Kari      | Storgt 20    | Stavanger |
+------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

I now want to return the names of the employees which have same city as that of 'Hansen Ola'. So i write a self-join and it works fine:

```
mysql> select p1.Lastname, p1.firstname from persons p1, persons p2 where p1.city =    p2.city and p2.lastname = 'Hansen';
+----------+-----------+
| Lastname | firstname |
+----------+-----------+
| Hansen   | Ola       |
| Svendson | Tove      |
+----------+-----------+
```

However, if i change the alias p2 to p1 i.e. p2.lastname = 'Hansen' to p1.lastname = 'Hansen', then i don't get names of both the employees.

```
mysql> select p1.Lastname, p1.firstname from persons p1, persons p2 where p1.city = p2.city and p1.lastname = 'Hansen';
+----------+-----------+
| Lastname | firstname |
+----------+-----------+
| Hansen   | Ola       |
| Hansen   | Ola       |
+----------+-----------+
```

Could somebody please help me understand why changing alias from p2 to p1 changes the result? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me highlight your query and hopefully it will make more sense:

```
select p1.lastname, ...
from persons p1, persons p2
where ... and p1.lastname = 'Hansen'
```

So you are limiting the results to only return records from the first table, p1.  And simultaneously you are restricting the first table to only be those with lastname = 'Hansen'.  If you picture the unrestricted result set, it may make more sense (I removed the abiguous portion of the `WHERE` clause to show the full product):

```
select p1.Lastname as p1_lastname, p2.lastname as p2_lastname
from persons p1, persons p2
where p1.city = p2.city

P1_LASTNAME     P2_LASTNAME
Hansen  Hansen
Svendson    Hansen
Hansen  Svendson
Svendson    Svendson
Pettersen   Pettersen
```

If you take the above resultset and add the condition `p1.lastname = "Hansen"`, it's no surprise you only get 'Hansen' out of it.

Answer (score 1):

The query is a little strange, and I'm not sure what basis it has in reality.  Essentially it joins a table with itself where the city column matches and then specifies that the `lastname` of one of the tables, which limits the results.  If you do `SELECT *` instead of selecting only limited rows, you can see that the table is being cross joined with itself and it is returning the cross product of the rows filtered by the `city` and `lastname` requirements.  The actual results are:

```
p1.firstname, p1.lastname, p2.firstname, p2.lastname
Hansen        Ola          Hansen        Ola
Hansen        Ola          Svendson      Toda
```

This is reversed in the original query because of the reversal of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query returns only those rows which contains  'Hansen'. it is not following self join.